# Can I change iOS lock screen wallpaper while keeping the default on home screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, wallpaper

I would like to change the wallpaper on my lock screen, on which the wallpaper is saved as png and added from Photos app. However, if I set it, the original home-screen background of my iOS (the one that you see at default, or when you reinitialized your iOS) is no longer available. The original seems to be recognized as “pairs” with its equivalent lock screen wallpaper, but is there any way to get the default wallpaper back again, while using my own wallpaper on lock screen?